# How does a “Sturmian root solver” work?

Tags: polynomials, numerical-methods, roots

At various points in the POV-Ray documentation, you can see sentences such as

> If this shape renders improperly you may [...] to turn off or on POV-Ray's slower-yet-more-accurate Sturmian root solver.

Buried away deeper within the documentation, you can find the following:

> Lower order polynomials are trivial to solve while higher order polynomials require iterative algorithms to solve them. One of those algorithms is the Sturmian root solver.

Does anybody have any idea what a “Sturmian root solver” might be or how it works? I'm curious to see what the algorithm looks like.

Comment: Using the Sturm sequence and the sign variations of it you can test if intervals contain real roots. This allows a bisection-exclusion scheme until you have isolated all the roots. I have no idea if that is actually implemented like this, but this comes to mind as combination of "Sturm" and "polynomial roots".

Comment: Sturm's theorem let you count the zeros in an interval. I guess using smaller intervalls, you can find the zeros. Here some details: https://web.math.ucsb.edu/~padraic/mathcamp_2013/root_find_alg/Mathcamp_2013_Root-Finding_Algorithms_Day_2.pdf